# TaskStackBuilder causes NoClassDefFoundError in AlarmReceiver

Tags: android, android-notifications

I'm creating android app that do a notification in a time that the user sets, when I set time and this time come, the App gives me the following Exception

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.app.TaskStackBuilder
 at com.emy.healthytips.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:114)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2397)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
```

In That Line of class AlarmReceiver.java

```
 TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
```

I spent long time trying in it and till now I can't reach to solution. Hope anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you running the app on, in terms of an API level? `TaskStackBuilder` was added in API Level 16 (Android 4.1).

Comment: I'm using Android 4.2.2

Answer (score 12):

I solved it by adding `import android.support.v4.app.TaskStackBuilder;` instead of 
`import android.app.TaskStackBuilder;`